# Annotate with intermediate model in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a two models Group and User.

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Group(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

A user can be in multiple groups and a group can have multiple users so I have made a ManyToManyField in Group.

I have made an intermediate model to store the date when the user was added to the group

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Group(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='GroupUser')

class GroupUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
```

It works as it should.

But I have a UserListView in which I want to annotate the number of groups each user belongs to.

I have overriden get_queryset in ListView

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return super(UserListView, self).get_queryset().annotate(num_groups=Count(?))
```

but I don't know how to count correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return super(UserListView, self).get_queryset().annotate(num_groups=Count('groupuser'))
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't

Comment: Can you give any more detail? 
Are you getting any errors? 
What is the output of super(UserListView, self).get_queryset() ?